# How to get full html when requesting page

Tags: python, request, urllib

I am working on scrapping web page which requires authentication and need full page html to scrap the data. I am using cookies to authenticate request.

I am not in favor of using selenium driver as it makes me open browser. I want this process to be running in backend.

I have tried it using requests and urllib.requests for this problem but it doesn't provide full html as we see in browser.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: If you go to the site without JavaScript active, do you see everything? My hunch is you will not. So something has to happen is wise in order for all of the data you are looking for to be available. That’s why people use selenium and playwright

Comment: If the site requires JavaScript to execute for the page to function, you'll need something like Selenium to execute that JavaScript.

Comment: Yes. Selenium can do the job but I don't want to use that.

Answer (score 0):

1. Using the requests library:

```
import requests

r = requests.get('http://www.google.com')

print(r.text)
```

2. Using the urllib library:

```
import urllib.request

with urllib.request.urlopen('http://www.google.com') as response:
   html = response.read()

print(html)
```

3. Using the selenium library:

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome()

driver.get('http://www.google.com')

html = driver.page_source

print(html)
```

4. Using the BeautifulSoup library:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

import requests

r = requests.get('http://www.google.com')

soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')

print(soup.prettify())
```

Comment: I am looking for solution in Python.